# How to target the Windows Store from an existing Windows Application type of project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-store-apps, monogame

Is it possible to re-target a Windows Application type of project to be a Windows Store project? I am trying to see if I can re-target the latest version of the [Farseer Physics Engine](https://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/) samples for MonoGame (.NET Framework targeted) to the Windows Store. I have tried searching but haven't found any good sources to support this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't any direct retargeting. You'll need to create a new project and then copy code over. How difficult that will be will depend on the specific code. Windows Store apps use a limited set of the .Net Framework (see [.NET for Windows Runtime apps](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=227049)).

The bulk of the physics engine is likely pure code rather than I/O and will be move across simply. You might want to target a Portable Class Library for this so the same library can be used in multiple targets.

Anything which accesses I/O, directly touches threads, etc. will likely need to be refactored to use the Windows Runtime instead of .Net API.

I believe Box2D has been ported to Windows Store, but I'm not sure offhand which versions.

Comment: Thanks for that, Rob. Yeah, it seems that refactoring the physics engine was a piece of cake. It has a `Serialization.cs` file which contains all of the world serialization logic that needs to be refactored for Windows Store. I got it into a Portable Class Library in minutes.